# Set two different debug levels in logger module

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have the following which creates two loggers -- stream logger and file logger.

```
# Set up the Logging modules
tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler(tmp_file.name)
c_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s]\t%(message)s'))
f_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s %(funcName)s:L%(lineno)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)
```

I would like the `Stream` loger to have level of `logging.INFO` (it is currently correct) and the `File` logger to have level of `logging.DEBUG`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Handler.setLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setLevel) method to set individual logging level for each handler, on top of the level set for the logger object:

```
tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # note here
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO) # note here
f_handler = logging.FileHandler(tmp_file.name)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # note here
c_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s]\t%(message)s'))
f_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s %(funcName)s:L%(lineno)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)
```

so that:

```
logger.debug('hi')
```

will produce a logging record to the temporary file while producing no output to the console.

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/SpryHeartfeltError

Answer (score 0):

You only have one `logger`, there,
and at any particular instant a given logger
has just one `level`.

Create `c_logger` and `f_logger`.
Give them each their own handler and logging levels.

Comment: can I give each of the handlers a different level? Or it's on the logger level?

Comment: @also -- how would I log to both loggers then in the same call?